# Godot: Area not detecting Kinematic body

Tags: godot

I have a 3d rts game where the enemy's troops auto-detect the player's troops, but it does not seem to work. In the troop script, I have:

```
func _on_EnemyZone_body_entered(body):
    if self.is_in_group("enemy") and body.is_in_group("player_troop") or self.is_in_group("enemy") and body.is_in_group("player_city"):
        body = enemy
        hunt = true
    if enemy == null and self.is_in_group("player_troop") and body.is_in_group("enemy"):
        body = enemy
        hunt = true
```

Either side can spawn this one troop scene, but whenever it is spawned by, say, the enemy, it is placed in the "enemy" group, and the same goes for the player. The problem is that when the EnemyZones of two troops on opposite sides come into contact, the EnemyZone body entered function does not even get called. What might be causing this?

Comment: What type is `EnemyZone`? Is ti an `Area` or a `KinematicBody`? Is there a case in which the code works?

Comment: `EnemyZone` is an `Area` node. The code works, but not at the right time. For example, I have trees in my scene which are kinematic bodies, and if I were to add a breakpoint in this code, it would trigger when `EnemyZone` would come into contact with a tree. But I want it to trigger when it comes into contact with another troop, which it does not appear to do.

Comment: This makes me think that your troops are not `KinematicBody`. Although, another possibility is that the `collision_mask` and `collision_layer` don't overlap.